# How do I edit checkout page to add note under Shipping Methods header?

Tags: checkout, template, magento2.2, custom-theme

How do I edit the checkout page and add a `<p>` under the Shipping Methods title? 
What templete file do I edit to get this

Something like this..

```
<li id="......">
    <div class="checkout-shipping-method">
        <div class="step-title">Shipping Methods</div>
            <p>Please select preferred pre-paid and added freight cost, 
               your UPS or FedEx Account or Your Special Carrier
             </p>
```

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_shipping_methods.html#method-item

Answer (score 0):

This will be in the checkout module, I believe, `vendors/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/methods.phtml`.

You'll probably want to copy the module over to your custom theme if you're using one to avoid making changes to the core files.